# Search field is already created in dataTable-- How do I add two more fields for search?

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am creating two fields out of my table for filter. I now want to search these fields in my dataTable.

My code:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#id').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#customer_id').val(), 10 );
        return false;
    }
);

var table = $('#return-table').DataTable();

$('#id, #customer_id').keyup( function() {
    table.draw();
});
```

For the above code I am getting:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: Which libraries you use ?

Comment: @hasnain -- I went through and tried to clean up this question a bit-- I cleaned up the code examples and tried to make the language a little more clear.  Please check I haven't changed the meaning of your question.  More information would also be helpful-- information on what libraries you are using would be helpful.  And are you sure you've posted all relevant code and error info? The StackOverflow community loves to help, and providing more meaningful info would help us help you. :)